# How to create SOAP API for custom_module in Magento 1.9.x?

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap-api-v2

How to create **SOAP API** for **custom_module in Magento 1.9.x?**

I have just started learning magento.

I tried to create an api for my custom module, in this with help of **SO & ME**, I tried like below `localhost/modules/api_custom_module.php`

```
$soap = new SoapClient('http://example.com/magentomodules/api/soap?wsdl=1');
$sessionId = $soap->login('admin', 'custom_module');
$result = $soap->call($sessionId, 'module.list');
$soap->endSession($sessionId);
```

It returns a string value

I have tried

`localhost/modules/api/soap/?wsdl` ->it shows some xml format.

When I tried in `localhost/modules/api_custom_module.php`, it returns string!

I would like to know:

which one is correct format?
what is the difference between these two results?

Thanks